# Compact Riemann surfaces are projective varieties

Tags: complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I am reading a proof of Chow's theorem from Mumford's complex projective varieties. The theorem establishes that every analytic subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^N$ is in fact, algebraic.

I have seen people cite this as proof that every compact Riemann surface $X$ is an algebraic curve. The way I understand it is that by Riemann existence, one constructs many meromorphic functions on $X$. So we pick a very ample divisor and embed $X$ into $\mathbb{P}^{g-1}$ by picking a basis for $L(D)$ and sending $x$ to $[f_1(x): \dots :f_g(x)]$.

I am not too sure why this embedding gives us an analytic subvariety though. Could someone elaborate this, or let me know if I'm understanding it incorrectly?

Comment: This was discussed many times on MSE.

Comment: Let $f_j$ be the one with the largest pole at $p$ then $[f_1(x): \dots :f_g(x)]=[f_1(x)/f_j(x): \dots : f_g(x)/f_j(x)] $ is holomorphic near $p$